# Segue won't trigger after logged into facebook using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, facebook

So I have managed to set it up so the whole login system works. It closes out of the browser once logged in but does not advance to the next viewController.

This is my AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
        app,
        open: url as URL!,
        sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String,
        annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
    )
}

public func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
        application,
        open: url as URL!,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
        annotation: annotation)
}
}
```

This is my ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

var fbLoginSuccess = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil && fbLoginSuccess == true)
    {
        print("Logged In...")
    } else {
        print("Not Logged In...")
    }

    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
    loginButton.center =   self.view.center

    loginButton.delegate = self

    self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// Facebook Login.

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

    if error != nil
    {
        print(error)
    } else if result.isCancelled {
        // Handle
    } else {
        fbLoginSuccess = true
        print("User logged in...")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showNew", sender: self)
    }

}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    print("User logged out...")
}

}
```

I have a storyboard Identifier 'showNew' and I cannot figure out why it doesn't trigger.

Comment: try this -: let viewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StoryBoardId") as UIViewController
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: @TusharSharma Where would I put this?

Comment: where you are printing (" user logged in")

Comment: @TusharSharma It throws and error and tells me to put a ';' between UIViewController and self.present.

Comment: self.present is a different line.

Comment: @TusharSharma Now I feel stupid haha

Comment: try this -: let viewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StoryBoardId") as UIViewController. After that -: self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: It still doesn't trigger it. @TusharSharma

Comment: Is it giving any error?

Comment: @TusharSharma I made a pastebin of what was left. https://pastebin.com/ZFNXQgAM

Comment: Got the solution for you-: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238925/segue-wont-trigger-after-facebook-login-with-swift

Comment: @TusharSharma Thank you! Will try it now!

Comment: sure and do let know if it worked.

Comment: @TusharSharma Still no luck I am going to stop for today.

Comment: you are doing the call in viewDidLoad do that in viewDidAppear.